# ruby on rails - getting the data of csv table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm having trouble getting the data from the csv table

this is my csv table

[image: product.csv]

this is my code in my model file where it's been called in my post method(create method in controller)

```
map = {}
table = CSV.read(File.open(csvpath, "r:bom|utf-8"), :headers => true) 
table.each do |row| 
    map[row['Sku Code']] = row['SKU Mfg Code']  
end

puts map
```

now the problem is my row['Sku Code'] and row['SKU Mfg Code'], couldn't find it's corresponding values in each row

basically what I'm doing is creating a dictionary with key being 'sku code' and it's value is 'SKU mfg code'.

can anyone help me here?

Comment: I'm writing code in ruby in VS code on windows... can anyone recommend what the best formatter to format the ruby code... somewhat like black for python code and prettier code formatted

Comment: I've tried rufo but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CSV.foreach`: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach

```
...
...
CSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
  map[row['Sku Code']] = row['SKU Mfg Code']
end
...
...
```